# Why you can read data from already closed ByteArrayOutputStream?

Tags: java, java-io, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm wondering why you still can read bytes from already closed `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Doesn't this line from docs mean the opposite?

> `public void close ()`: Closes this stream. This releases system resources used for this stream.

***Sample code:***

```
String data = "Some string ...";
ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(bOut);
dOut.write(data.getBytes());
dOut.close();
System.out.println("Length: " + bOut.toByteArray().length);
System.out.println("Byte #2: " + bOut.toByteArray()[2]);
```

***Output:***

```
Length: 15
Byte #2: 109
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where you close `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you have closed the  `DataOutputStream`

Comment: @MitulSanghani When you close a stream, any nested streams are closed as well.

Comment: ok Thanks i don't know that..

Comment: Because that's what it's for. It wouldn't be much use if you couldn't get  the data out of it afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) just copies what it has in the buffer; it's not reading anything more from the stream.

```
public synchronized byte[] toByteArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(buf, count);
}
```

Also this class is a bit special. See [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close()) and code.

> Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect. The methods in this class can be called after the stream has been closed without generating an IOException.

```
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

`close()` does not really do anything.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought close() should flush underlying buf. But it seems like it doesn't